# How to extract specific values and populate in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I m parsing a json feed containing three tags they are Name,Status,Image and storing it in an NSMutableArray.if my "status" is "1" ,i got to return the data corresponding to the "Name" tag within the braces and populate it my table view.the problem is if its true.i m able to return only single value and it populates the entire tableview below is the json structure,code and screenshot.

**JSON STRUCTURE**

```
{
    Image = "http://dev-parkguiden.knutpunkten.se/Content/Images/Icons/icon8.png";
    Name = "Caf\U00e9/restaurang";
    Status = 0;
},
    {
    Image = "http://dev-parkguiden.knutpunkten.se/Content/Images/Icons/icon9.png";
    Name = "Kiosk ";
    Status = 0;
},
    {
    Image = "http://dev-parkguiden.knutpunkten.se/Content/Images/Icons/icon10.png";
    Name = "Toalett finns";
    Status = 1;
},
    {
    Image = "http://dev-parkguiden.knutpunkten.se/Content/Images/Icons/icon11.png";
    Name = "Parkeringsm\U00f6jligheter";
    Status = 1;
},
    {
    Image = "http://dev-parkguiden.knutpunkten.se/Content/Images/Icons/icon1.png";
    Name = Minigolf;
    Status = 1;
},
```

XCODE

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}

for ( int i=0; i<[self.media1 count]; i++) 
{

    NSDictionary *boy=[self.media1 objectAtIndex:i];


NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",boy];
    //NSLog(@"the value:%@",str);

    if([str isEqualToString:@"1"])
    { 
        //NSDictionary *hai=[[boy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"1"];
    //  NSLog(@"the values availbale:%@",hai);
        cell.textLabel.text=[self.story objectAtIndex:i];
            return cell;

   }
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of you are using for loop you get the last match records at once. why you are using for loop in table. you have to check the values outside and make a new array and then assign that array in to table. also post some more code so i can solve your problem

```
-(void)makeNewArray
{
for ( int i=0; i<[self.media1 count]; i++) 
{

    NSDictionary *boy=[self.media1 objectAtIndex:i];


    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",boy];
    if([str isEqualToString:@"1"])
    { 
        [newArray addObject:[self.story objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}
[tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return newArray.count;
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}
        cell.textLabel.text=[newArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            return cell;

}
```

Comment: is der any possibility of getting the entire value.if i used it outside the table view?

Comment: yes just make a new array in your for loop. but out side table view after making of new array then reload table with new array

Comment: cocoa Matters:dude dat totally worked .but the problem wat i m getting is if i m to scroll my tableview after a specific point it crashes any idea.i m getting this in my log screen..Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds [0 .. 6]

Comment: Yes dude because you have to assign numberOfRowsAtIndexPath array value check updated answer